# How can I edit mpsyt config file?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I tried adjusting the settings in .config/mps-youtube/config, but the config file looks like this:

[image]

Do I need a special programm to edit this file?

Comment: +1 for making me aware of mps-youtube. Installed it and LOVE IT.

Comment: yeah its pretty good when it works

Comment: @Rinzwind just in case. If you ever run into the problem where mps-youtube opens up a videoplayer where you just wanted to listen to music, set playerargs --video=no in console and make sure mpv is your player. Set show_video to true and playerargs to "" if you want video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"config" is a data file, not a text file that holds options. See the "transcode"  file in the same directory.

```
$ more transcode
# transcoding presets for mps-youtube
# VERSION 0

# change ENCODER_PATH to the path of ffmpeg / avconv or leave it as auto
# to let mps-youtube attempt to find ffmpeg or avconv
ENCODER_PATH: auto

# Delete original file after encoding it
# Set to False to keep the original downloaded file
DELETE_ORIGINAL: True

# ENCODING PRESETS

# Encode ogg or m4a to mp3 256k
name: MP3 256k
extension: mp3
valid for: ogg,m4a
command: ENCODER_PATH -i IN -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 256k OUT.EXT

# Encode ogg or m4a to mp3 192k
name: MP3 192k
extension: mp3
valid for: ogg,m4a
command: ENCODER_PATH -i IN -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k OUT.EXT

# Encode ogg or m4a to mp3 highest quality vbr
name: MP3 VBR best
extension: mp3
valid for: ogg,m4a
command: ENCODER_PATH -i IN -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 OUT.EXT

# Encode ogg or m4a to mp3 high quality vbr
name: MP3 VBR good
extension: mp3
valid for: ogg,m4a
command: ENCODER_PATH -i IN -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 OUT.EXT

# Encode m4a to ogg
name: OGG 256k
extension: ogg
valid for: m4a
command: ENCODER_PATH -i IN -codec:a libvorbis -b:a 256k OUT.EXT

# Encode ogg to m4a
name: M4A 256k
extension: m4a
valid for: ogg
command: ENCODER_PATH -i IN -strict experimental -codec:a aac -b:a 256k OUT.EXT

# Encode ogg or m4a to wma v2
name: Windows Media Audio v2
extension: wma
valid for: ogg,m4a
command: ENCODER_PATH -i IN -codec:a wmav2 -q:a 0 OUT.EXT
```

These are the options for transcoding.

Editing the configuration is done from within mpsyt using the "set" command. See `help config` inside mpsyt.

Comment: sorry I didn't read your post correctly

Comment: naah I made an edit ;-) searched for a way to edit config but it is a data file with no method other than from inside mpsyt